# Using WMI on a remote machine

Tags: client, wmi, external, diagnostics

Is it possible at all to obtain WMI information (within C#.NET) from an external source such as a hard drive with a Windows installation on?

I ask this because I'm making an automated diagnostic utility for A-Level Computing, and there are often times when the remote machine may not boot, so a host machine needs to connect somehow to the faulty machine to exchange information.

If this isn't possible, do you know any way in which I can achieve this effect (e.g. by booting into a minimal operating system such as Hiren's Boot and running the .NET application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't, to access the WMI the Windows OS and the [`WMI Service`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd363658%28WS.10%29.aspx) must be running in the remote machine.

Comment: But could it be run on a machine using a minimal version of Windows? (ie, Hiren's Boot CD)

Comment: Only If the WMI service is running.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to wake the machine, WMI is a service, if it isnt running then you cant Query it.